# Render reactjs with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I should use `node.js`. I would like to use `reactjs` to render my views. but there are some questions.

1. pre-defined functions inside `reactjs` like `componentDidMount` will work?
2. I should use `redux`, is it possible?
3. which of routing I should use (`react` or `express.js` router)?

Comment: 1 - Yes, 2 - Yes, 3 - Wut ? React is a frontend framework, you caa do your frontend routing using `react-router` and your backend routing using express

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Predefined functions like componentDidMount will totally work as well as the other lifecycle events in React.

2) Yes, it's possible, Redux is great for app-state management and preserving data to be used inside the application for each instance.

3) You should make use of both React-Router and Express. You can use React-Router to navigate on the front-end, navigating from page to page. For Express, it's especially useful for developing API routes for your backend if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes
2. Yes, It is possible
3. react-router is for internal App routing. Where Express.js can only route to /index.html on main source.

> Eg: myapp.com/reactapp -> done by Express, where index.html is on
>   /reactapp myapp.com/myapp/new/view --> here /new/view is routed by
>   react